# Query to find random 5 users that current_user isn't following

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've done my due diligence and haven't been able to figure out this problem.

I'm trying to find a random set of 5 users, that (1) cannot be the current_user and (2) cannot already be followed by the current_user.

I'm trying to put this into the variable `@users`. My relationships are set up where Users have `followed_users` (which are the users they are following), and Users have `followers`.

**User model**

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                  class_name: "Relationship",
                                   dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
```

**Relationship model**

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User", touch: true
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User", touch: true
```

Unfortunately, I'm terrible at queries so I'm not sure how to find this array of users. On top of a solution that one of you would implement, any resources where I can learn on my own how to do queries efficiently would be really appreciated.

If you  need any more code to help solve the problem, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
User.includes(:reverse_relationships)
    .where("#{Relationship.table_name}.follower_id <> :id", id: current_user.id)
    .where("users.id <> ?", current_user.id)
    .order("RAND()")
    .limit(5)
```

Not sure about the RAND() function, it depends on your DB.

Eventually replace the `id <> :id` with `id NOT IN (?)` to be able to pass more than just one id:

```
scope :some_other_users, lambda { |user_ids|
  user_ids = user_ids.kind_of?(Array) ? user_ids : [user_ids]
  includes(:reverse_relationships)
    .where("#{Relationship.table_name}.follower_id NOT IN (?)", user_ids)
    .where("users.id NOT IN (?)", user_ids)
    .order("RAND()")
    .limit(5)
}
```

---

```
query_getting_followed_user_ids = Relationship.where("follower_id IN (?)", [current_user.id]).select("relationships.followed_id").to_sql
User.where("id NOT IN (#{query_getting_followed_user_ids})")
    .where("id <> ?", current_user.id)
    .order("RAND()")
    .limit(5)
```

As you can see, I want to make a query on the result of an other query: **Query-ception**!

Comment: I can also count on your @MrYoshiji for these queries! haha I'm getting the error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "reverse_relationships"`. I will update my question to clarifiy, maybe I wasn't giving enough info

Comment: Do I just need to replace `reverse_relationships` with `relationships`? `Relationships` is the table in my database

Comment: Hmm yes use the real name of the table, I should have seen that ;) (updated my answer in consequence)

Comment: Well thanks! It's actually giving me a list of 3 users that the current_user is already following, not a list of users that the current_user is NOT following.

Comment: I just updated my answer @Justin, not sure if it will work but we're getting close ^^

Comment: That's awesome @MrYoshiji! Well done! Only thing it doesn't do is exclude the current_user but I should be able to figure that out. Any resources online where I can learn how to do these queries?

Comment: I added the `.where("id <> ?", current_user.id)` clause which should solve the last issue. I don't know any resources online to learn about this, especially in Rails, but you can find a lot about Sub-Querying: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm